# "once put" vs. "once it is put"

Tags: ellipses

Is the ellipsis of "it is" in the following sentence acceptable/preferred?

> Once [it is] put in the context of philosophy of language, the
>   problem X can be recast as follows.

Such ellipse after *once* seems to be more popular than when full verb comes after it. [Source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=once%20put%2C%20once%20it%20is%20put&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Conce%20put%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conce%20it%20is%20put%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: How are you eliminating false positives like 'I once put in 20 hours shovelling snow with only two short breaks'? // Google searches for "Once [it is] put in the context" seem to support your hypothesis. Either sounds fine (in your example) to my ears.

Comment: If you remove "it is", *once* can potentially be read in the sense of '*although it was once*'. The present tense in *it is* avoids that reading.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would like to know your view on the other comment by Lawrence.

Comment: @Sasan In other examples, quite possibly (though the verb-forms usually disambiguate). Here, it's an extremely unlikely reading. You'd really need two sentences to juxtapose two statements connected so loosely. ???'Once a Boy Scout, he gets tired rather quickly.' Grammatical, but I'd say unacceptable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would like to know your view on this question as well: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403952/the-right-verb-for-when-we-want-others-trust-for-a-longer-time/403961#403961

Comment: Your sentence will be clearer if you drop the "Once".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Once" is a subordinating conjunction here in the sense "when" or " as soon as". Like any other adverbial conjunction "once" can also locate the action of the main clause in the time frame being subservient but lending meaning to the main clause. ' Once ' may  precede an adverbial clause or phrase.

Without "it is" the first part of the sentence is a reduced adverbial clause, a phrase. All 0/-ed/-en forms with out tense conjugation are passively adjectival. You're at liberty to use the reduced clause or its unabridged form. It's a matter of preference, nothing more to it.

Answer (score 1):

Once can also be used as a synonym of when. In addition to that, you can also use "on" or "upon" if you want to use fewer words in your sentence. So, instead of saying;

> When the box was opened, it caught fire.

You can say;

> Upon being opened, the box caught fire.