# Which verb should I use that means to have somebody's trust for a long time?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, collocation

What is the right verb for when we want others' trust for a long period? Do we ***keep***, ***retain***  or  ***preserve*** their trust ... ?

Example:

> By speaking only the truth I can ... their trust for a long time.

For sure, all of the above suggestions are here or there used. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep%20their%20trust%2Cpreserve%20their%20trust%2Cretain%20their%20trust&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckeep%20their%20trust%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreserve%20their%20trust%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cretain%20their%20trust%3B%2Cc0) seems to confirm this. But I want to know which one sounds the most idiomatic.

Comment: (a) 'Preserve' seems a choice here that not many favour (looking at the Ngram results you post, and general Google data). It sounds _very_ formal. I'd have to have a good reason to choose this. Your example doesn't warrant the 'active effort needed' refinement that 'preserve', as davidlol points out, gives. The other two are both fine in my opinion; I wouldn't use 'retain' down at the pub (assuming I went).

Comment: The most idiomatic sounding verb is **win** but **gain** is also good. `By speaking only the truth I hope to win their trust for a significantly long period.` See: http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search1?word=trust

Comment: Some of the Ngram results are using the phrases in a different sense e.g. a financial trust, or people (retaining etc.)  their (own) trust in something. I suspect it would be more idiomatic to say "by not lying to then I'll make  them  trust me", or "by being honest with then I'll get them to trust me".  It may depend on 1. Do they already trust you and 2. Are you trying to describe e.g. to an accomplice, how you will get/keep someone's  trust so that when you do lie they will believe you, or are you just saying that when they realise  you are honest they will trust you?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why did you voted for closing the question?

Comment: “keep” is fine. I would choose ‘‘maintain’’ over ‘‘retain’’, especially in the context of doing *something* (speaking only the truth) to avoid losing their trust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep their trust , or retain, their trust means simply that you will continue to be trusted by them. It does not imply any action on your part.

To preserve something usually means to take some action that will have the effect of keeping it.

In the example given:

> By speaking only the truth  ...

you are taking some action (telling the truth) to achieve your purpose, that of keeping, or retaining, something. The action you are taking is a method of preservation, the tactic by which you intend to keep their trust.

So

> By speaking only the truth I can **preserve** their trust for a long time.

is most appropriate here. You are explaining by what means you consciously and deliberately intend to hold on to their trust. You are revealing your cunning plan.

Comment: Why not *maintain* or *secure*, though? *Preserve* does not even make the top 80 collocations on COCA, is it something that people actually use? What about *uphold*? What about *continue to earn*? Any word on *cultivate*? And surely you can't be saying that I cannot *keep* things as soon as I make a conscious effort to keep them. Surely I can totally keep your trust even if I do work real hard on keeping it, no?

Comment: @RegDwigнt What do you mean by "Preserve does not even make the top 80 collocations on COCA"?

Comment: @RegDwigнt The question is edited. Would like to know your view.

Comment: The question is edited. Would like to know your view

Comment: @Sasan COCA is perhaps the most used corpus for determining how the English language is actually used (especially in the US). You can look it up; you can even use it for free. Reg is saying that the string 'preserve their trust' seems prettyy unidiomatic. There are a reasonable number ...

Comment: [of Google hits](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22preserve+their+trust%22+-rights&oq=%22preserve+their+trust%22+-rights&gs_l=psy-ab.3...12248.15038.0.15942.8.8.0.0.0.0.80.442.8.8.0.foo%2Cersl%3D1%2Cfett%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-45%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-09%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-045%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-1125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-15%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-25%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-06%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-0075%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-0525.2..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.2HMtCRRoNF8), however.//